# Creating Objects on the fly in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like a critique of the following method I use to create objects:

In the interface file:

```
MyClass * _anObject;
...
@property (retain, nonatomic) MyClass * anObject;
```

In the implementation file:

```
@property anObject = _anObject
```

so far, so simple. Now let's override the default getter:

```
(MyClass *) anObject {
    if(_anObject == nil) {
        self.anObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        [_anObject dowWhateverInitAction];
    }
    return _anObject;
}
```

**EDIT:**
My original question was about creating the object only (instead of the whole life-cycle), but I'm adding the following so that it doesn't through off anyone:

```
- (void) dealloc {
   self.anObject = nil;
}
```

**/EDIT**

The main point of the exercise is that setter is used inside the getter. I've used it for all kind of objects (ViewController, myriad other types, etc.) The advantage I get is:

- An object is created only when needed. It makes the app pretty fast
  (for example, there are 6-7 views in an app, only one gets created in
  the beginning).
- I don't have to worry about creating an object before it's used... it happens automatically.
- I don't have to worry about where the object will be needed the first time... I can just access the object as if it were already there and if it were not, it just gets created fresh.

Questions:

- Does it happen to be an established pattern?
- Do you see any drawbacks of doing this?

Comment: Pretty common pattern, it's usually called lazy initialization.

Comment: Do you have ARC turned on? If you don't, then there's a memory leak. You need to release the object you created with `[[MyClass alloc] init]` after assigning it to the instance variable with the `self.anObject` syntax. What you're doing is the recommended pattern for most situations.

Comment: I personally do not like getters with side-effects. Yes, lazy-loading is common but I would totally refrain from using it all over my app but only for views that hold many subviews (as done by the UIViewController already).

Comment: @Till the *entire point* of getter methods is to add some side effect. If you don't need a side effect of some kind, then there is no point even using a getter method at all. You might as well just use the `_anObject` variable directly (it's faster, and less code).

Comment: I haven't mentioned it here, but the objected gets released in the dealloc.

Comment: If you've got a dealloc method, that implies you are not using ARC. You absolutely have a memory leak then, and the object is not being deallocated in your `dealloc` method. You need to release or autorelease the object in the `dealloc` method ***AND*** at the point where you are creating it (usually just `[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease]` will do the trick). `self.anObject = foo` will retain the object for you. You will want to read up a bit more on memory management in Obj-C, or just turn ARC on.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert introducing sideeffects certainly is not the only point of getters - but maybe I should not start arguing right here ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is an established pattern. I often use lazy instantiation like this as an alternative to cluttering up `-init` or `-viewDidLoad` with a bunch of setup code. I would assign the value to the instance variable instead of using the synthesized setter in the event that this object ends up being created as a result of something happening in `-init`.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern is quite commonly used as a lazy-loading technique, whereby the object is only created when first requested.

There could be a drawback to this approach if the object being created lazily takes a fair amount of computation to create, and is requested in a time-critical situation (in which case, it doesn't make sense to use this technique). However I would say that this is a reasonable enough thing to do should the object be quick to create.

Comment: Lazy loading usually isn't done in time-critical situations, in time-critical situations you want to *pre-load* and *cache*, not delay. Lazy loading is typically used in other situations, i.e. when something takes a while to load but isn't always needed.

Comment: Yes that was my point really, you wouldn't use this technique in time-critical situations. I'll edit my answer to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong with your implementation (assuming you’re not using ARC yet) is that you’ve got a memory leak—using the setter means that your `MyClass` instance is getting over-retained. You should either release or autorelease `_anObject` after that initialization, or assign its value directly instead of calling the setter.

Aside from that, this is totally fine, and it’s a good pattern to follow when the MyClass is an object that isn’t necessarily needed right away and can be recreated easily: your response to memory warnings can include a `self.anObject = nil` to free up the instance’s memory.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a decent [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization). Philosophically, one can argue that the drawback is that a getter has a side effect. But the side effect is not visible outside and it is kind of an established pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy instantiation is an established pattern, and it is used by Apple in their (terrible) Core Data templates.

The main drawback is that it is overly complex and often unnecessary.  I've lost count of the number of times I've seen this where it would make more sense to simply instantiate the objects when the parent object is initialised.

If a simple solution is just as good, go with the simpler solution.  Is there are particular reason why you can't instantiate these objects when the parent object is initialised?  Perhaps the child objects take up a lot of memory and are only rarely accessed?  Does it take a significant amount of time to create the object and you are initialising your parent object in a time-sensitive section of your application?  Then feel free to use lazy instantiation.  But for the most part, you should prefer the simpler approach.

It's also not thread-safe.

Regarding your advantages:

> An object is created only when needed. It makes the app pretty fast (for example, there are 6-7 views in an app, only one gets created in the beginning).

Are you referring to views or view controllers?  Your statement doesn't really make sense with views.  I don't normally find myself needing to store view controllers in instance variables/properties at all, I instantiate them when I need to switch to them and push them onto the navigation stack, then pop them off when I'm done.

Have you tried your app without using this pattern?  Conjecture about performance is often wrong.

> I don't have to worry about creating an object before it's used... it happens automatically.

No, now you have to worry about writing a special getter instead.  This is more complex and prone to mistakes than simple instantiation.  It also makes your application logic and performance more difficult to understand and reason about.

> I don't have to worry about where the object will be needed the first time... I can just access the object as if it were already there and if it were not, it just gets created fresh.

You don't have to worry about that when you instantiate it during your parent object's initialisation.

Comment: Thread-safety/atomicity can be trivially implemented with `@synthesized` just like any other manually implemented getter. Also, lazy loading doesn't really complicate much, I don't find it overly complex at all. Even just looking at the 5 lines of code it is not difficult to see what is going on. A simple `// create only when used` comment as a hint wouldn't do anyone any harm either, if you think it will make it any easier to understand.

Comment: Isn't all of this very subjective and a question of style and preference? I personally see it exactly like Jim and act upon but I do understand your point @dreamlax.

Comment: @Till: Mostly it is style and preference but also it can be for performance as well; for example, there is no point allocating and initialising an object (especially one that takes a long time to load) that is only needed in 20% of cases, in these cases it is better to allocate it when it is needed to speed up the other 80%.

Comment: @dreamlax yes, agree - loading "heavy" objects in a lazy style helps if those objects are rarely used.